# friend class and the scope of function arguments

Tags: c++, friend-class

I'm writing a reflection utility for self usage, I simplified the code(remove complicated templates) as below:

```
class A {
 private:
  friend class Field;
  int i;
};

class Field {
 public:
  Field(int A::* p) : p(p) {}
 private:
  int A::* p;
};


Field field(&A::i);
```

the compiler complains about `i` is private of class `A`.

I'm confused now, I know that parameters have a scope of **function prototype scope**, but I don't know much about it's relationship with the C++ feature friend classes.

Can anyone help what should I do to pass the private `&A::i` to the `field` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
Field field(&A::i);
```

you are accessing a private data member pointer (`&A::i`) from within a toplevel scope. This is not related to the class `Field` being a `friend` of `A`. What you could do instead, is giving `friend` access to a function that is supposed to instantiate `Field` objects, e.g.

```
class Field;

class A {
 private:
  friend Field createField();
  int i;
};
```

The definition of `Field` itself can remain unchanged, while the builder function could be

```
Field createField()
{
    // Works: &A::i is a private member, but createField is a friend
    return Field{&A::i};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone help what should I do to pass the private `&A::i` to the `field` object?

It depends on whether `A::i` is accessible at the caller side; because `&A::i` is passed as the argument at the caller side.

For example, `Field` is friend of `A`, then `A::i` is accessible in `Field`. e.g.

```
Field() : p(&A::i) {}
```